# Realm Studio not importing diacritics from csv file

Tags: android, csv, realm

i am trying to create realm database from existing CSV file, but the problem is, realm studio is converting diacritics into question marks.
like "ä" is converted into "�".

[image]

Comment: what the encoding of your csv file ? Try to convert it to UTF-8

Comment: the csv is exported using sqllite studio, i am not sure of encoding, if i open this file with notepad then save it as utf-8 realm studio does not import id column.

Comment: I suggested UTF-8 but maybe it's another encoding you have to use, can't help you more than that :/